# Filling array of objects from the user's input in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a java application  that's allows the user to make a catalog for a supermarket, and then display all the products that the user entered to the catalog. Now I have a problem with filling the array of objects the should be fill in by the user's input. 
The output should be like the following (user input in **Bold**):

Enter product description (or # to stop): **Condensed Powdered water**
Enter product code: **P3487**
Enter product unit price: **$2.50**
Enter product unit phrase: **per packet**

Enter product description (or # to stop): **Distilled Moonbeams**
Enter product code: **K3876**
Enter product unit price: **$3.00**
Enter product unit phrase: **a dozen**

Enter product description (or # to stop): **Anti-Gravity Pills**
Enter product code: **Z9983**
Enter product unit price: **$12.75**
Enter product unit phrase: **for 60**

Enter product description (or # to stop): **#**

Your catalog:
P3487, Condensed Powdered water, $2.50 per packet.
K3876, Distilled Moonbeams, $3.00 a dozen.
Z9983, Anti-Gravity Pills, $12.75 for 60.

The code that I wrote : 2 classes
class 1:

```
public class Catalog {

private String description ; 
private String code ;
private double price ;
private String phrase ;

int counter = 0;

private Catalog [] list = new Catalog [100];

public Catalog (String productDescription , String productCode , double    productPrice , String productPhrase)
{
    description = productDescription;
    code = productCode;
    price = productPrice;
    phrase = productPhrase;
}

public void setDescription (String productDescription)
{
    description = productDescription;
}

public String getDescription ()
{
    return description;
}

public void setCode (String productCode)
{
    code = productCode;
}

public String getCode ()
{
    return code;
}

public void setPrice (double productPrice)
{
    price = productPrice;
}

public double getPrice ()
{
    return price;
}

public void setPhrase (String productPhrase)
{
    phrase = productPhrase;
}

public String getPhrase ()
{
    return phrase;
}
```

class 2:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class CatalogTest {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String name = null; 
    String code = null;
    double price = 0.0;
    String phrase = null;



    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader  (System.in));

    Catalog product = new Catalog(name,code,price,phrase);

    Catalog [] productsArray = new Catalog [100];


    for (int i = 0 ; i < productsArray.length ; i ++)
    {


        System.out.println("Enter product description (or # to stop): ");
        name = input.readLine();

        if (!("#".equals(name))) 
        {

            productsArray [i] = product;
            product.setDescription(name);

            System.out.println("Enter product code: ");
            code = input.readLine();
            productsArray [i] = product;
            product.setCode(code);


            System.out.println("Enter product unit price: ");
            price = Double.parseDouble(input.readLine());
            productsArray [i] = product;
            product.setPrice(price);


            System.out.println("Enter product unit phrase: ");
            phrase = input.readLine();
            productsArray [i] = product;
            product.setPhrase(phrase);



            productsArray [i] = new Catalog (name,code,price,phrase);



        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Your Catalog:");

            System.out.printf("%s, %s,$%.2f   %s",product.getCode(),product.getDescription(),product.getPrice(),product
                    .getPhrase());
            break;
        }


    }


}
}
```

The output I get (user input in **Bold**) :
Enter product description (or # to stop): 
**condensed powdered water**
Enter product code: 
**p3487**
Enter product unit price: 
**2.50**
Enter product unit phrase: 
**per packet**
Enter product description (or # to stop): 
**distilled moonbeams**
Enter product code: 
**k3876**
Enter product unit price: 
**3**
Enter product unit phrase: 
**a dozen**
Enter product description (or # to stop): 
**#**
Your Catalog:
k3876, distilled moonbeams,$3.00 a dozen

So any help PLEASE ??

Comment: I haven't read your question fully, but haven't you considered using an `ArrayList` instead of an array?

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb... but what is your question?

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code that works...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CatalogTest
{

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String name = null;
        String code = null;
        double price = 0.0;
        String phrase = null;

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));

        Catalog product = new Catalog(name, code, price, phrase);

        Catalog[] productsArray = new Catalog[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.length; i++)
        {

            System.out.println("Enter product description (or # to stop): ");
            name = input.readLine();

            if (!("#".equals(name)))
            {

                productsArray[i] = product;
                product.setDescription(name);

                System.out.println("Enter product code: ");
                code = input.readLine();
                productsArray[i] = product;
                product.setCode(code);

                System.out.println("Enter product unit price: ");
                price = Double.parseDouble(input.readLine());
                productsArray[i] = product;
                product.setPrice(price);

                System.out.println("Enter product unit phrase: ");
                phrase = input.readLine();
                productsArray[i] = product;
                product.setPhrase(phrase);

                productsArray[i] = new Catalog(name, code, price, phrase);

            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Your Catalog:");
                for (int j = 0; j < productsArray.length; j++)
                {
                    if(productsArray[j]!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.printf("%s, %s,$%.2f %s,",
                            productsArray[j].getCode(),
                            productsArray[j].getDescription(),
                            productsArray[j].getPrice(),
                            productsArray[j].getPhrase());
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have another question, Can I use the method sort() to sort the array according to the code entered by the user?

Comment: You can make Catalog implement Comparable. Inside compareTo method, you use logic to compare the product code. You can then use Collections.sort to sort according to product code..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not elaborating on the correct answer that has been given but in the future it may be beneficial to look into [ArrayLists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [Vectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). Both are much nicer data structures to use when you are unsure of the amount of items you need to store as they are growable data stores i.e. you don't need to define the size of them when initialising.

For example in your original attempt you defined the `productsArray` to be of size 100. What if the user wanted to input 101 items? Using a Vector would combat this as it can grow or shrink according on the fly.

I'm a 3rd year software development student and when I started to use Vectors over Arrays programming problems became a lot easier to work around because of the flexibility Vectors offer :)

Comment: I have another question, Can I use the method sort() to sort the array according to the code entered by the user?